# How to link to d3.js-v3 source file without getting code 301/304 or TypeError

Tags: javascript, d3.js, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-304

d3 is currently on v5, but I need to use v3. I am trying two ways to access v3:

1. Including `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>` in my HTML  tag.
2. Including `<script src="d3.min.js"></script>`, where the `d3.min.js` is a source file in d3.zip, downloaded from https://github.com/d3/d3/releases?after=v4.2.5.

With the first way, nothing from my code shows up. I get Code 301 and/or Code 304. Apparently d3js.org is not hosting source files for older versions?

With the second way, still nothing from my code shows up, even though I have the actual source file in my own folder. If I look at the console in the browser, I see that I am getting TypeErrors such as `TypeError: e is undefined [Learn More] d3.min.js:1:15253`.

Note: I'm using python's SimpleHTTPServer.

How can I get d3 v3 to work?

Comment: There is something else going on here, because `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>`**is** working in fact... you don't need CDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using CDN. E. g. https://cdnjs.com/libraries/d3
You can pick any version there.